# How do i create Intent and to where to put the codes?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to follow the lesson [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#RespondToButton/) and now im stuck on "Building an Intent". I am quite confused for how to make this Intent and where to paste it. Can someone show me the step by step process on this tutorial? I am getting massive headaches now. Please I want to learn to do this.

> Build an Intent
>
> An Intent is an object that provides runtime binding between separate
>   components (such as two activities). The Intent represents an app’s
>   "intent to do something." You can use intents for a wide variety of
>   tasks, but most often they’re used to start another activity.
>
> Inside the sendMessage() method, create an Intent to start an activity
>   called DisplayMessageActivity:
>
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); The
>   constructor used here takes two parameters:
>
> A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity
>   class is a subclass of Context) The Class of the app component to
>   which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the activity
>   that should be started)

Answer (score 1):

As the tutorial says, you need to add the line of code that creates an new instance of the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) class. You will use this instance later to tell the OS to launch another activity or a service. In this particular example, the `Intent` you are building will direct the OS to launch the `DisplayMessageActivity`.

To do this step properly, you need to modify the **sendMessage** method that you have added in the previous step of the tutorial. The final method should look something like this:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

After creating the `Intent`, the code will take the content of the `editText` control in the current activity, assign it to the `message` variable, and then add it as an additional parameter to the `intent`, so that the target `DisplayMessageActivity` activity can do something with it.

Don't worry about the DisplayMessageActivity yet. It will be added in a later step.

Comment: im confused again where can i exactly input that codes?? in the Mainactivity.java??? here is my current code in Mainactivity.java

Comment: im confused again where can i exactly input that code youve just shown me?? in the MainActivity.java?? i dont know exactly where to modify the "sendMessage" here is the code in my MainActivity.java

Comment: here is my last input code in MainActivity.java following the /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}

Comment: Yes, you should put that code in the `MainActivity.java`. Also, don't forget to add all the necessary `import` statements.

Btw, none of the comments has any code. You might want to update the question instead, and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i create Intent and to where to put the codes?

You want to open the activity using intent then you can write your code in this method.

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```